# Reprojecting raster with FME?

Tags: raster, coordinate-system, fme-form, mosaic, nodata

I have multiple .tiff + .tfw files in EPSG:3067, which I need to reproject to EPSG:3878. I tried to do it with FME, and succeeded, kind of. The geotiffs are placed well, but some weird white area appears between the grid (see image attached) when I add the orthophotos to ArcMap 10.4. I used CsmapReprojector, "ignore heights" was selected and interpolation type was Bicubic and Cell Size was "Preserve Cells". I also defined source and destination coordinates manually to 3067 and 3878.

So what did I do wrong while 3878 reprojection looks like this:

[image]

While it should look like this:

[image]

Comment: Mosaic in original projection, re project result

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Agree to the comment of @FelixIP, one possible solution is to first create a whole raster using **RasterMosaicker** transformer, then reproject and re-tile the Raster with **RasterTiler** transformer. This can be a ressource consuming approach, if you have many input tiles. Another approach is to apply nodata values with the **RasterBandNodataSetter** (Value = 0) or **RasterPaletteNodataSetter**, but this depends on color model and output data format.

[image]

Mosicking and projecting the mosaic (and re-tiling and applying nodata value) results in

[image]

where in the uppermost part applying nodata did not work properly, because FME creates an alpha-band in this area for some reason.

Projecting the tiles directly and applying nodata values results in

[image]

where the lines between the tiles are display artefacts in FME data inspector in this case.

Comment: Hi,many thanks for your answer! It helped a lot! I have multiple rasters, so I first tried the "RasterBandNodataSetter". First it did not work, when added after reprojector, but then i tried to add RasterPaletteNodataSetter also, right after RasterBandNodataSetter, and it worked like charm! No more white areas and it reprojects rasters at ok speeds.

Answer (score 2):

Can't add image to comment, so I'll add here how I were able to succeed with Jochen Schwarzes help.

[image]

I tested this with 11 rasters, which went through fine. The result of this reprojection in Arcmap looks good.

Answer (score 2):

Since You have ArcGIS, You could make a mosaic dataset with the rasters, and use the mosaic dataset as input to FME. This solution works well for me with large datasets.

Ed: ArcGIS has the ability to reproject  the mosaic dataset on fly. That means that You have the option of choosing if the reprojection should be done by ArcGIS or FME. With a large dataset, it is likely that ArcGIS can reproject the dataset faster than FME, who sees the dataset as a large raster.